# Queries executed from SQL Server and Pyodbc results in different output

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to make a code that executes the SQL queries into my SQL Server using Pyodbc. The selected temporary table from the queries will be then exported to csv file. However, it seems like the result output is different from what it should be.

When the queries are ran in the SQL Server prompt, it returns 235 rows of table.
But when it is ran with Pyodbc, it returns 32.

The code is this:

```
# Set up a connection to your SQL Server
server =  server_name
database = db_name

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;, timeout')

# Set up a cursor to execute SQL queries
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Define file paths
query_file = query_directory
output_file = output_directory

# Read the SQL query from the text file
with open(query_file, 'r') as f:
    queries = f.read()

# Execute the query

try: 
    cursor.execute(queries)
    print('\n' + ' SQL Queries Executed Sucessfully')
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    print(f'\nError executing query: {queries}')
    print(f'\nError: {ex}')

# Fetch the results
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Get the column names
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

# Create a DataFrame from the results and column names
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=columns)

# Export the result to a CSV file
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)

# Close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

The SQL code is here: https://github.com/kun-w-lee/random/blob/main/SQL
I believe the problem is occurring with SQL's while loop because #ProfileData_DomainsOnly would produce 32 rows as well.

What problem is Pyodbc code producing here so the SQL function is not being processed correctly?

Comment: Try adding  `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the beginning of your SQL script file.

Comment: *"it returns 235 rows of table. But when it is ran with Pyodbc, it returns 32."*...was it the same sql ?